# Incorrect password on first login to Kali Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, passwords, kali-linux

I tried to install Kali Linux on VirtualBox following this [guide](https://youtu.be/TGOiAsSdADs) on Youtube

As per the guide, there was no setup page, as Kali Linux was configured. When I turned on the machine, it booted and went straight to the login page.

I tried `root` as username and `toor` as password, but it said incorrect password. I tried leaving the password blank, still didn't work.

This is my first time dealing with Kali. What should I do now? Are there any alternate passwords?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

username: kali
password: kali

note: qwerty keyboard by default

Comment: Welcome on the SU! It is some like a default user name in Kali linux? If yes, please explain it in an edit of your post.

Comment: Please explain to the user exactly what you are trying to tell them. It is they're first logon to Kali Linux, they may not understand what it is you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up Kali (I have Kali running here - and in a Virtual Machine), it will ask you to create a password for the root account.  Do that and that will be the password. There is no preset password.

Try setting up the Virtual Machine again and this time, watch for the root account creation process and set up the password of your choice.

Once running, create a regular account and, if you wish, set it up as an admin account:

```
sudo useradd -m YOUR_USERNAME
sudo passwd YOUR_USERNAME  # (asks you to create a new password and do that)
sudo usermod -a -G sudo YOUR_USERNAME
```

Comment: note that when adding a user this way you should later run `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username` or the login shell will be sh which points to dash and wont let you use arrow keys or tab autocomplete.

Comment: Although switching to default zsh shell, I've just learned, is one of the new things that comes with kali 2020.04.