# how to run sudo command in kali 2020.1

Tags: linux, sudo, root

I know that kali linux 2020.1 does not support root user.

but I have following case

when I installed it on my pc (i368) it has black screen login, I tried starting lightdm service but failed. now I am going to install gdm3 but I do not have any repository and source.list is unwriteable for me. it needs root access, I tried logging as root/toor but failed.

can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1522358/incorrect-password-on-first-login-to-kali-linux-in-virtualbox/1522364#1522364

Answer (score 0):

Kali 2020.1 definitely supports Root access. There is no default password for Root - you need to provide that when you set up Kali first.

You can run commands from a regular user as sudo command and provide admin access, but some commands (update and upgrade) need to run from Root.

You still have the same question open here:

[Incorrect password on first login to Kali Linux in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1522358/incorrect-password-on-first-login-to-kali-linux-in-virtualbox/1522364#1522364)

Answer (score 0):

user=kali password=kali on main entrance
then open terminal
then type in terminal sudo su
then type kali if asked for password
then type in your new password you wanna use twice the same
if doesnt prompt new password type in passwd root
it should prompt new password
type in your password of choosing twice
and you golden i believe and makes sure to remember your password cause youll need it to use root i hope this helps i seen on interweb and followed it
and it worked for me
you guys can thank someone elsethis is not my knowledge im just passing it along how i believe i seen it.